# how to download dynamci file from database using dropdown

Tags: laravel, download

i want to download file using dropdown, dropdown is looping from database like this :

[image]

[image]

this is controoler **DataController** method **index()** for showing filename  from database:

```
public function index()
{

    $data = Document::select('filename')->get();
    return view('testdata', compact('data'));
}
```

this is **download function** for download file deppendds filename, when i select **Burger.jpg** so downloaded file should be **Burger.jpg**

```
public function download(Request $request)
{
    $data = Document::find($request->filename);
    return response()->download(public_path($data));

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

but when i select **Burger.jpg**, downloaded file is **sow.docx**, i select **carbon.png**, downloaded file also **sow.docx**, alwasy **sow.docx**,

[image]

this is my form action:

```
<form 
    method="get" 
    action="{{route('download')}}" 
    accept-charset="UTF-8" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" name="filename" id="input-filename">
            <option value="">
                Select data
            </option>

            @foreach($data as $datas)
                <option value="{{$datas->id}}">{{$datas->filename}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</form>
```

this is my database view :
[image]

how to download based on **id** ?

when i select **Burger.jpg** so downloaded **Burger.jpg**, when i select **sow.docx**, downloded is **sow.docx**???
how to be like that ??
thanks

Comment: laravel version please

Comment: laravel 5.4.36.

Comment: have you tried

`public function download(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input();
}`

to see what the request is being passed to the controller?

Comment: can you share your dropdown code

Comment: dropdown code 

<form 
    method="get" 
    action="{{route('download')}}" 
    accept-charset="UTF-8" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" name="filename" id="input-filename">
            <option value="">
                Select data
            </option>

            @foreach($data as $datas)
                <option value="{{$datas->id}}">{{$datas->filename}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</form>